# Unity c# List memory leak

Tags: c#, list, memory-leaks, unity-game-engine

I'm getting a serious memory leak when assigning textures at runtime.

When useNewArray is true, Task manager shows that Unity's memory usage grows by ~20 MBs / second.

The full (183k zipped) project can be downloaded here:
https://goo.gl/axFJDs

Here's my code:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;

public class testMemory : MonoBehaviour {

public bool             useNewList = false;
Texture2D               newTexture;
public byte             color;
List<Color>             newColors;
List<byte>              staticPixelColorsList;
Color                   tempColor = Color.white;

// Use this for initialization
void Start () {

    newTexture = new Texture2D(0,0);
    newColors = new List<Color>();
    staticPixelColorsList = new List<byte>(120000);
    GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = newTexture;
}

// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {

    // Make sure we're using different colors for every frame
    color = (byte)((Time.time*255) % 255);

    if(useNewList)
    {
        // This option causes a memory leak, but it's the one I need 
        // because I'm getting the texture data from an external source
        int newWidth  = Random.Range(200,400);
        int newHeight = Random.Range(200,400);

        // Create a new list each time
        List<byte> newPixels = new List<byte>(newWidth * newHeight);
        for(int i = 0; i < newWidth * newHeight; i++)
        {
            newPixels.Add ((byte)(color * i / 120000f));
        }
        setTexture(newPixels, newWidth, newHeight);

        // Clear the list (yeah, right)
        newPixels.Clear ();
    }
    else
    {
        // Use the same list, but assign new colors
        for(int i = 0; i < 120000; i++)
        {
            staticPixelColorsList.Add ((byte)(color * i / 120000f));
        }
        setTexture(staticPixelColorsList, 300, 400);
        staticPixelColorsList.Clear ();
    }
}

void setTexture(List<byte> inputPixels, int inputWidth, int inputHeight)
{
    newTexture.Resize(inputWidth, inputHeight);

    float colorValue;

    // Convert input value to Unity's "Color"
    for(int n = 0; n < newTexture.width * newTexture.height ; n++)
    {
        colorValue = inputPixels[n] / 255.0f;
        tempColor.r = tempColor.g = tempColor.b = colorValue;
        newColors.Add (tempColor);
    }

    // Actually set the texture pixels
    newTexture.SetPixels(newColors.ToArray());
    newTexture.Apply();
    newColors.Clear();
}
}
```

Thanx in advance.

Comment: "but it's the one I need because I'm getting the texture data from an external source" So your real code does or doesn't use a list of byte?

Comment: Golly, why are you updating a texture CPU-side **every frame**?  That'll be quite slow

Comment: @weston This is the code used to reproduce the problem..
MickyDuncan, The texture comes from a camera and I do need to update it every frame.
T.Kiley, when 'useNewList = false' I'm using a pre-allocated list with other values. The problem may be that runtime-allocated lists are not GC'ed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently this is a bug with Texture2D.Apply(). It's so deep, Unity's profiler did not show the leak, but external tools did. Unity have acknowledged the problem and are seeking out a solution. No date was given. Thanks for the help :-)

Answer (score 2):

According to this [MSDN Article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwb5h52a%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), the `List<T>.Clear` method resets the `Count` property to 0 and releases all references to elements of the collection.

However, the capacity remains unchanged. Therefore, the same amount of memory stays allocated. To release this memory, the `TrimExcess` method should be called, or the `Capacity` property manually set.

Maybe instead of making a new `newPixels` list each time the `Update` method is called you could create this list outside of the function (perhaps in the class declaration) and refill it each time the `Update` method is called? Clearing would be optional, since every call, the contents would be overwritten. This could also improve performance, since your code won't have to release every member of the collection at the end of every update.

Comment: To check this is correct, the OP could try calling a `System.GC.Collect()` to check the memory is then free'd (i.e. not a memory leak, simply an inefficient use of memory.

Comment: I've added '
 newPixels.TrimExcess();
        System.GC.Collect();'
after 'newPixels.Clear ();'
It didn't make any difference. Nor did using one list and not a new one each Update().

Comment: @T.Kiley Calling `GC.Collect()` after a `List<T>.Clear()` when the list is a list of _value types_  will have no effect

Comment: @MickyDuncan No - I was proposing doing it at the start of the next frame where the last frames `newPixels` will have gone out of scope and therefore be available for GC

Comment: @T.Kiley I understand, that's fine

Comment: @user754317 I don't understand, isn't using one list the same as what happens if `useNewList == false` ?